# Place anchor tag and html in same line

Tags: html, razor

I have the below cshtml Code

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="column masthead__join masthead__join_hideInMobile">
            <a rel="nofollow"
               href="@Url.Action("New", "Discuss")"
               class="thread-follow button ui-kit-button-medium">
                <span class="button__text">
                    New discussion
                </span>
            </a>
            <form class="column search header__search" action="/search.asp" method="get" data-component="search">
                <input id="landing-header-search" class="search__input" type="text" name="searchterm" value="" placeholder="Search Forums Group / Discussion" data-modal-focus data-search-input autocomplete="off" />
                <input type="hidden" name="collections" value="Forum_Group" />
                <button class="button ui-kit-button-medium" type="submit">
                    <span class="button__text">Search</span>
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>              
    </div>
```

the components are seperated in the next line. I want it to be in the same line. Also search button should be merged with textbox

Actual :

[image]

Expected:

[image]

Comment: Can we see your CSS as well please?

Answer (score 0):

To get all elements to appear on one line the easiest way is to:
Set white-space property to nowrap on a parent element that has overflow-x: auto set to show horizontal scrollbars.
Have display: inline-block set on all child elements.
For example:
HTML:

```
<ul id="parent">
<li>Box #1</li>
<li>Box #2</li>
<li>Box #3</li>
```

CSS:

```
#parent {
list-style: none;
width: 100%;
height: 90px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;


}


#parent > li {
display: inline-block;
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
background-color: red;
}
```